# Validar formato 12b1234 en Shell

Tags: linux, shell, sh

soy nuevo en shell y estoy intentando de validar dos datos por medio de 2 if, el primero es dato="12b1234" y el segundo es dato2="02.04.020". pero no se como hacerlo ya que intento de todas las formas y obtengo errores.

if [[ $TATO =~ ^"[0-9]{2}[a-z]{1}[0-9]{4}$" ]]; then
echo "Match"
else
echo "No Match"
fi

al ejecutar estas lineas para la primera validación tengo el error:

TestShell.sh: line 56: conditional binary operator expected
TestShell.sh: line 56: syntax error near `=~' TestShell.sh: line 56:` if [[ $TATO =~ ^"[0-9]{2}[a-z]{1}[0-9]{4}$" ]]; then'

Comment: como estas ejecutando el script? si tiene permisos de ejecucion, normalmente la primera linea sera `#!/bin/bash`, por lo que deberias ejecutar tu comando con `bash script.sh`. A mi tu codigo me esta funcionando bien.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta..... era mi version de bash 2.05, pero ya lo corregí con un grep